# Unsigned and suffix for integer in C

Tags: c, variable-assignment

The following code is ok, the compiler won't produce any warnings. But how can `int` store `unsigned int`?

```c
int c = UINT_MAX;
int d = 4294967295;
long int h = ULONG_MAX;
```

The following code produces warning, but why? These are basically the expanded version of `long int h` variable definition above:

```
long int i = 18446744073709551615;
unsigned long int j = 18446744073709551615;
```

Here is the warning message:

```
88308218/source.c:14:18: warning: integer constant is so large that it is 
     unsigned long int i = 18446744073709551615;
88308218/source.c:15:27: warning: integer constant is so large that it is 
     unsigned unsigned long int j = 18446744073709551615;
```

The following code is ok. It is similar to the definition of `int d` above, but with suffix `u`. It seems like type specifier is weaker than integer suffix. The same question about `unsigned` value stored within a variable without `unsigned` type also arises.

```
long int k = 18446744073709551615u;
```

Here is the source code of the example:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

int main(void)
{
  // how can unsigned val be stored in normal int without prop type (unsigned int)
  // nor with suffix (u/U)
  int c = UINT_MAX;
  int d = 4294967295; // ok, same question with c
  long int h = ULONG_MAX; // ok, same question with c
  // the following produces warning, why? this is basically just expanded ver of h
  long int i = 18446744073709551615;
  long int j = 18446744073709551615u;
  unsigned long int k = 18446744073709551615;

  printf("%u\n", c);
  printf("%u\n", d);
  printf("%lu\n", h);
  printf("%lu\n", i);
  printf("%lu\n", j);
  printf("%lu\n", k);

  return 0;
}
```

The result of the compilation:

```
$ gcc source.c
source.c: In function 'main':
source.c:12:16: warning: integer constant is so large that it is unsigned
   12 |   long int i = 18446744073709551615;
      |                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
source.c:14:25: warning: integer constant is so large that it is unsigned
   14 |   unsigned long int k = 18446744073709551615;
      |                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Comment: Since you seem to have looked up the `define` corresponding to e.g. `UINT_MAX`, compare it exactly to what you have here. The differences are going to have a lot to do with the warning.

Comment: Always enable and build with extra warnings. I typically build with `-Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic`. One of them includes the warning option `-Woverflow`, which will give you a warning for `int d = 4294967295;`

Comment: The reason for the "constant is so large" warning for 1844... is that that number is too large to fit into any signed integer type that the compiler has available. On the other hand, the number 4294... *does* fit into an integer type, specifically a 64-bit integer. So the compiler is simply informing you that it's going to treat 1844... as an unsigned number even though you didn't tell it to (by using a `u` suffix).

Comment: As for assigning `UINT_MAX` to an `int` type: that's going to cause integer overflow, which is undefined behavior. In other words, don't do that. As for assigning 4294... to an `int` type: that might be ok, if an `int` happens to be 64 bits or larger. Otherwise, it's undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how can `int` store `unsigned int`?

`int` only store `int`s.

Before the assignment, there is a conversion to `int`.  When an integer type value outside the `int` range is converted to an `int` as in `int c = UINT_MAX;`, the value is converted to an `int` in an *implementation specified* manner.  Avoid code like this - it is not portable.

---

**Not OK**

Following code produces 3 warnings.  Enable more warnings like `-pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Wconversion` or seek a better compiler.  These warnings are nicely showing the *implementation specified* value of the conversion.

```
int c = UINT_MAX;
// warning: signed conversion from 'unsigned int' to 'int' changes value from '4294967295' to '-1' [-Wsign-conversion]

int d = 4294967295;
// warning: overflow in conversion from 'long int' to 'int' changes value from '4294967295' to '-1' [-Woverflow]

long int h = ULONG_MAX;
// warning: signed conversion from 'long unsigned int' to 'long int' changes value from '18446744073709551615' to '-1' [-Wsign-conversion]
```

---

Decimal integer constants `18446744073709551615`, lacking a `u` are *signed*.  This value  is outside the `long long` range - hence the warning.

```
long int i = 18446744073709551615;
// warning: integer constant is so large that it is unsigned

unsigned long int j = 18446744073709551615;
// warning: integer constant is so large that it is unsigned
```

Use `18446744073709551615u` instead as that is inside the `unsigned long long` range.

`long int i = 18446744073709551615u;` will still warn as part of the next step: conversion.  The now good `unsigned long long` constant is outside the `long long` range.

```
long int i = 18446744073709551615u;
// warning: signed conversion from 'long unsigned int' to 'long int' changes value from '18446744073709551615' to '-1' [-Wsign-conversion]

unsigned long int j = 18446744073709551615u;
// OK
```

---

**Not OK**

The following warns for similar reasons as above.

```
long int k = 18446744073709551615u;
// warning: signed conversion from 'long unsigned int' to 'long int' changes value from '18446744073709551615' to '-1' [-Wsign-conversion]
```

Answer (score 0):

From C11 standard (ISO/IEC 9899:2011) http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1124.pdf , (6.4.4.1, page 55-56)

> The type of an integer constant is the first of the corresponding list
> in which its value can be represented.

```
int
long int
long long int
```

So, by default decimal integer constants are signed integers. We need to provide suffixes for other types (As per C11 document).

1. > how can int store unsigned int?

It cannot store. As some one pointed out in comments, you need to enable extra warnings using `-Wall  -Wextra  -Wpedantic` options.

2. > The following code produces warning, but why?

   ```
    long int i = 18446744073709551615;
    unsigned long int j = 18446744073709551615;
   ```

Reason : As per C11 standards, `j` is still a `signed long integer` since you did not add suffix `ul`. That's why compiler throws such a warning to `unsigned long integer`. And `long integer i` cannot store that value.

Comment: Please see the quote from C11 document. I provided link. Please see it.

Comment: Term `Integer constant` is used,  not `decimal Integer constant `

Comment: Thank you for pointing it. I am referring to C11 not C99.

Comment: Comment cleaner coming through beep beep.